# Html is not being filtered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form for creating topics (aka tags):

```
<%= simple_form_for @video, :url => {:action => "topic_update"}, :html => {:id => "topic_form"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="topic_field_input">
      <%= f.input :topic_names, :class => "topic_field", :label => false, :placeholder => "Type a topic (enter to create new one)" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I create it as a virtual attribute:

```
attr_accessor :topic_names
after_save :assign_topics

def assign_topics
    self.topics << @topic_names.map do |name|
      Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name.split(' ').map {|w| w.capitalize }.join(' '))
    end
  end
end
```

I'm thinking that it doesn't filter the html because what I'm passing to `find_or_create_by_name`

How would I modify the code to filter the html?

Comment: off topic, but `name.split(' ').map {|w| w.capitalize }.join(' ')` can be replaced by `name.titleize()`

Answer (score 0):

You can force the escaping with `ERB::Util.h(@topic_names)` in the setter or getter.